# paypal sandbox account response failed

Tags: paypal

I am trying to test the integration of  the paypal into the website. I created two sandbox accounts in the developer.paypal.com and ensured there are sufficient funds in both of them.

In the code below you will notice the logic. The money is deducted from the buyer sandbox account and also credited to the facilitator sandbox account without any issues (screenshot attached) but the response is received as "FAIL" which meant I could not proceed

```
    string authToken = "token provided";
    string txToken = Request.QueryString["tx"];
    string query = "cmd=_notify-synch&tx=" + txToken + "&at=" + authToken;

    //Post back to either sandbox or live
    string strSandbox = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
  //  string strLive = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strSandbox);

    //Set values for the request back
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    req.ContentLength = query.Length;
    //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
    StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
    streamOut.Write(query);
    streamOut.Close();
    StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
    string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
    streamIn.Close();

    Dictionary<string, string> results = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    if (strResponse != "")
    {
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(strResponse);
        string line = reader.ReadLine();

        if (line == "SUCCESS")
        {

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                results.Add(line.Split('=')[0], line.Split('=')[1]);

            }
            Response.Write("<p><h3>Your order has been received.</h3></p>");
            Response.Write("<b>Details</b><br>");
            Response.Write("<li>Name: " + results["first_name"] + " " + results["last_name"] + "</li>");
            Response.Write("<li>Item: " + results["item_name"] + "</li>");
            Response.Write("<li>Item Number: " + results["item_number"] + "</li>");
            Response.Write("<li>Amount: " + results["payment_gross"] + "</li>");
            Response.Write("<hr>");
        }
        else if (line == "FAIL")
        {
            // Log for manual investigation
            Response.Write("Unable to retrive transaction detail");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //unknown error
        Response.Write("ERROR");
    }
```

The error is in "strResponse" which I receive as "FAIL"

Comment: Can you provide the raw API request and response that you're getting?

Comment: Oh, nevermind, it looks like you're just working with Payments Standard as oppose to the API.  Are you getting an error code or some message of any kind?  "FAIL" doesn't help much.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, we have since solved the issue once. the link that helped us was https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer/. We basically were not using the correct AuthToekn